# Kommasetzung in dieser Aufzählung

Tags: punctuation, comma, list

Wie muss die Kommasetzung in dieser Aufzählung aussehen?

> Für den Anwendungsserver, die Anwendungen und, in diesem Fall auch, die Automationssoftware wird eine Java-Laufzeitumgebung benötigt.

Nach Gefühl würde ich es so schreiben, jedoch scheint mir das nicht richtig:

> Für den Anwendungsserver, die Anwendungen und in diesem Fall auch die Automationssoftware, wird eine Java-Laufzeitumgebung benötigt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insgesamt ist nur ein Komma nötig:

> Für den Anwendungsserver, die Anwendungen und in diesem Fall auch die Automationssoftware wird eine Java-Laufzeitumgebung benötigt.

Ein Komma vor *wird* wäre falsch, denn adverbiale Bestimmungen werden nicht mit Komma abgetrennt. Man kann, wenn man will, *in diesem Fall auch* (oder nur *in diesem Fall*) als Einschub auffassen und mit Kommas abtrennen wie in der ersten Version in der Frage. Stilistisch besser wären allerdings Gedankenstriche:

> Für den Anwendungsserver, die Anwendungen und – in diesem Fall – auch die Automationssoftware wird eine Java-Laufzeitumgebung benötigt.

Comment: So oder so, sobald das Wort "auch" eingefügt wird, würde ich zusätzlich das Wort "für" noch mal wiederholen: "Für den Server, die Anwendungen und auch für die Automationssoftware wird ..." Erst recht wenn man mit "in diesem Fall" noch eine Unterbrechung hat.

Comment: Ach ja, und lass den Konjunktiv sein: Ein Komma vor wird **ist** falsch ;) Sonst stimme ich aber voll und ganz zu.

Comment: Super! Vielen Dank für die ganze Hilfe! Werde die Version mit den Gedankenstrichen um das zweite "für" ergänzen und verwenden. Upvote ist leider erst mit 15Rep möglich :(